# Factorial digit sum

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, factorial

### The challenge is to calculate the digit sum of the factorial of a number.

---

Example

```
Input: 10
Output: 27
```

10! = 10 × 9 × ... × 3 × 2 × 1 = 3628800,
and the sum of the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27

You can expect the input to be an integer above 0.
Output can be of any type, but the answer should be in the standard base of the coding language.

---

Test cases:

```
10    27
19    45
469   4140
985   10053
```

N.B. Some languages can not support large numbers above 32-bit integers; for those languages you will not be expected to calculate large factorials.

[OEIS link here](https://oeis.org/A004152) thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in characters wins!

Comment: What's the maximum input number to expect? With 32-bit integers in R this challenge can't be solved accurately past `n>21`

Comment: @Billywob For R then you will only need to go to 20. I shall edit question to reflect this

Comment: Great challenge!

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
!SO
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IVNP&input=MTA)

```
!   Factorial.
 S  Push characters separately.
  O Sum.
```

Answer (score 11):

### [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
!DS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=IURT&input=&args=MTA)

Does what you expect:

```
!    Factorial.
 D   Decimal digits.
  S  Sum.
```

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Tr@IntegerDigits[#!]&
```

Comment: came here to type these exact characters.

Comment: Why `[#!]` and not `@#!`? (Mathematica noob)

Comment: @Cyoce because `@` has higher precedence than `!`.

Answer (score 8):

## C++11, 58 bytes

As unnamed lambda modifying its input:

```c++
[](int&n){int i=n;while(--n)i*=n;do n+=i%10;while(i/=10);}
```

One of the rare cases when my C++ code is shorter than the [C code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100844/53667).

If you want to suppport larger cases, switch to **C++14** and use:

```c++
[](auto&n){auto i=n;while(--n)i*=n;do n+=i%10;while(i/=10);}
```

and supply the calling argument with `ull` suffix.

Usage:

```c++
auto f=
[](int&n){int i=n;while(--n)i*=n;do n+=i%10;while(i/=10);}
;

main() {
  int n=10;
  f(n);
  printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>63</s> <s>61</s> <s>53</s> 38 bytes

New approach thanks to manatwork:

```
->n{eval"#{(1..n).reduce:*}".chars*?+}
```

Old:

```
->n{(1..n).reduce(:*).to_s.chars.map(&:hex).reduce:+}
```

- -3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender
- -5 bytes thanks to G B

Comment: The old boring `eval` way: `->n{eval"#{(1..n).reduce:*}".chars*?+}`.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*Thanks to @Kade for saving me a byte*

`sj.!QT`

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sj.%21Q10&input=10&debug=0)

This is my first time using Pyth, so I'm sure that my answer could be golfed quite a bit.

Explanation:

```
s Sum
  j the digits of
    .! the factorial of
      Q the input
    T in base 10
```

Comment: `10` is assigned to a variable `T`, so you can make this `sj.!QT` :)

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll add it

Comment: Nice! [``ssM`.!``](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssM%60.%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A19%0A469%0A985&debug=0) does the job too, also in 6 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
f x=sum$read.pure<$>(show$product[1..x])
```

Usage example: `f 985` -> `10053`.

Make a list from `1`to `x`, calculate the product of the list elements, turn it into its string representation, turn each character into a number and sum them.

Edit: @Angs saved a byte. Thanks!

Comment: `f x=sum$read.pure<$>(show$product[1..x])` saves a byte

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r=1:n and f(n-1,r*n)or sum(map(int,str(r)))
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/E6Vu)**

Comment: I just came up with a slightly worse version of this that looks *way* too similar for it to be a separate answer. Bravo

Answer (score 5):

### R, <strike>58</strike> 53 bytes

Edit: Saved one byte thanks to @Jonathan Carroll and a couple thanks to @Micky T

```
sum(as.double(el(strsplit(c(prod(1:scan()),""),""))))
```

Unfortunately, with 32-bit integers, this only works for `n < 22`. Takes input from stdin and outputs to stdout.

If one would like higher level precision, one would have to use some external library such as `Rmpfr`:

```
sum(as.numeric(el(strsplit(paste(factorial(Rmpfr::mpfr(scan()))),""))))
```

Comment: I reached the exact same answer as you did, then found a 1-byte gain on `c(x,"")` vs `paste(x)`: `sum(as.integer(el(strsplit(c(factorial(scan()),""),""))))`. Coerces the factorial result to character and `strsplit` returns it as a second list, so `el` still works and extracts the first list elements.

Comment: how about `prod(1:scan())`?

Comment: also `as.double ` should suffice

Comment: @MickyT Thanks! Updated.

Comment: `strtoi` works as a shorter replacement `as.double`, I think.

Comment: A bit of playing around with splitting digits gives me this now `sum(utf8ToInt(c(prod(1:scan()),''))-48)` for 39

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
$+$*++,a
```

[Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=JCskKisrLGE&input=&args=MTA)

**Explanation**

```
      ,a    # range
    ++      # increment
  $*        # fold multiplication
$+          # fold sum
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually managed to post an 05AB1E answer before you ;).

Comment: @carusocomputing: Hehe. Got me the opportunity to look into a new language :)

Comment: I think you're the first one besides me to use Pip for a non-polyglot code golf answer. :D

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 8 bytes

```
rim!Ab:+
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmltIUFiOis&input=MTA)

#### Explanation

```
r   e# Read input.
i   e# Convert to integer.
m!  e# Take factorial.
Ab  e# Get decimal digits.
:+  e# Sum.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 8 bytes

-3 thanks to @Razetime - i forgot to drop a paren lol

```apl
+/⍎¨∘⍕∘!
```

Explanation:

```apl
+/⍎¨∘⍕∘!
       !  ⍝ factorial of ⍵
     ⍕    ⍝ convert to string
  ⍎¨      ⍝ produce digit vector
+/        ⍝ sum all digits
```

Has some problems with factorial of 900, this code will work fine for `⍵>40`:

```apl
b←({⍵⊣⍵.⎕CY'dfns'}⎕NS⍬).big
↑(+b/(⍎¨∘⍕∘(↑(×b/⍳))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfmv8ahvqlsQkAgI0HzUNsHQyMJcwdjkfxqQra2v8ai379CKRx0zHvVOBZKKj7oWaf4HqgVKpikYGnDBmZZwprHBfwA)

Comment: [-3](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfmv8ahvqlsQkAgI0HzUNsHQyMJcwdjkfxqQra3/qLfv0IpHHTMe9U4Fkor/gcqA4mkKhgZccKYlnGls8B8A "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: `1⊥10⊤!` should work I guess (since you're using Extended). That said, the 8 byter works without Extended.

Comment: @Bubbler I was interested mostly in stock Dyalog APL-only solutions. I'll change it to Dyalog Unicode soon-ish

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>63 60 53</s> 51 bytes

```
->n{a=0;f=(1..n).reduce:*;f.times{a+=f%10;f/=10};a}
```

Thanks to Martin for golfing help.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 148 bytes

```
int s=1,ret=0;while(i>1){s=s*i; i--;}String y=String.valueOf(s);for(int j=0;j<y.length();j++){ret+=Integer.parseInt(y.substring(j,j+1));}return ret;
```

Comment: @EyalLev There is no limit specified in the question. How are you expecting long to handle a factorial that equates to larger than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807?

Answer (score 3):

### bash (seq,bc,fold,jq), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

Surely not the most elegant but for the challenge

```
seq -s\* $1|bc|fold -1|jq -s add
```

Comment: `fold -1` saves a byte.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma corrected! thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
$!@e+
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=JCFAZSs&input=OTg1&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

Basically the described algorithm:

```
$!       Take the factorial of the Input
  @e     Take the elements of this factorial (i.e. its digits)
    +    Output is the sum of those elements
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 4 bytes

```
fsS#
```

Give input on the command line: `$ pushy facsum.pshy 5`. Here's the breakdown:

```
f      % Factorial of input
 s     % Split into digits
  S    % Push sum of stack
   #   % Output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 30 bytes

```
@(n)sum(num2str(prod(1:n))-48)
```

Calculates the factorial by taking the product of the list `[1 2 ... n]`. Converts it to a string and subtracts `48` from all elements (ASCII code for `0`). Finally it sums it up :)

Answer (score 3):

### C, 58 bytes

This is not perfect. Only works ones because a have to be -1 in start. The idea is to use two recursive function in one function. It was not as easy as I first thought.

```
a=-1;k(i){a=a<0?i-1:a;return a?k(i*a--):i?i%10+k(i/10):0;}
```

Usage and understandable format:

```
a = -1;
k(i){
   a = a<0 ? i-1 : a;
   return a ? k(i*a--) : i? i%10+k(i/10) :0;
}

main() {
   printf("%d\n",k(10));
}
```

Edit:
I found metode that let use this function multiple time but then length is 62 bytes.

```
a,b;k(i){a=b?a:i+(--b);return a?k(i*a--):i?i%10+k(i/10):++b;}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't quite understand why it wouldn't be shorter to use one function to return the factorial and another to calculate the digit sum, like a(b(10)). Is the word "return" too long for that to work?

Comment: Return eats much. I try that of course. Maybe someone can do it at least i couldn't get that work

Comment: you could accept two arguments to save a few bytes: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153132/77415

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{[+] [*](2..$_).comb}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [+]           # reduce the following with ｢&infix:<+>｣

    [*](        # reduce with ｢&infix:<*>｣
      2 .. $_   # a Range that include the numbers from 2 to the input (inclusive)
    ).comb      # split the product into digits
}
```

Comment: Congrats, you got answer no. 101010!

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek That's nothing, on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337), and [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert) I am user number 1337

Answer (score 3):

## Cubix, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
u*.$s.!(.01I^<W%NW!;<,;;q+p@Opus
```

Net form:

```
      u * .
      $ s .
      ! ( .
0 1 I ^ < W % N W ! ; <
, ; ; q + p @ O p u s .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=dSouJHMuISguMDFJXjxXJU5XITs8LDs7cStwQE9wdXM=&input=MTA=&speed=2000)

## Notes

- Works with inputs up to and including 170, higher inputs result in an infinite loop, because their factorial yields the `Infinity` number (technically speaking, its a non-writable, non-enumerable and non-configurable property of the window object).
- Accuracy is lost for inputs 19 and up, because numbers higher than 2<sup>53</sup> (= 9 007 199 254 740 992) cannot be accurately stored in JavaScript.

## Explanation

This program consists of two loops. The first calculates the factorial of the input, the other splits the result into its digits and adds those together. Then the sum is printed, and the program finishes.

### Start

First, we need to prepare the stack. For that part, we use the first three instructions. The IP starts on the fourth line, pointing east. The stack is empty.

```
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
0 1 I . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

We will keep the sum at the very bottom of the stack, so we need to start with `0` being the sum by storing that on the bottom of the stack. Then we need to push a `1`, because the input will initially be multiplied by the number before it. If this were zero, the factorial would always yield zero as well. Lastly we read the input as an integer.

Now, the stack is `[0, 1, input]` and the IP is at the fourth line, the fourth column, pointing east.

#### Factorial loop

This is a simple loop that multiplies the top two elements of the stack (the result of the previous loop and the input - n, and then decrements the input. It breaks when the input reaches 0. The `$` instruction causes the IP to skip the `u`-turn. The loop is the following part of the cube. The IP starts on the fourth line, fourth column.

```
      u * .
      $ s .
      ! ( .
. . . ^ < . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Because of the `^` character, the IP starts moving north immediately. Then the `u` turns the IP around and moves it one to the right. At the bottom, there's another arrow: `<` points the IP back into the `^`. The stack starts as `[previousresult, input-n]`, where `n` is the number of iterations. The following characters are executed in the loop:

```
*s(
*   # Multiply the top two items
    #   Stack: [previousresult, input-n, newresult]
 s  # Swap the top two items
    #   Stack: [previousresult, newresult, input-n]
  ( # Decrement the top item
    #   Stack: [previousresult, newresult, input-n-1]
```

Then the top of the stack (decreased input) is checked against `0` by the `!` instruction, and if it is `0`, the `u` character is skipped.

#### Sum the digits

The IP wraps around the cube, ending up on the very last character on the fourth line, initially pointing west. The following loop consists of pretty much all remaining characters:

```
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
. . . . . W % N W ! ; <
, ; ; q + p @ O p u s .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

The loop first deletes the top item from the stack (which is either `10` or `0`), and then checks what is left of the result of the factorial. If that has been decreased to `0`, the bottom of the stack (the sum) is printed and the program stops. Otherwise, the following instructions get executed (stack starts as `[oldsum, ..., factorial]`):

```
N%p+q;;,s;
N          # Push 10
           #   Stack: [oldsum, ..., factorial, 10]
 %         # Push factorial % 10
           #   Stack: [oldsum, ..., factorial, 10, factorial % 10]
  p        # Take the sum to the top
           #   Stack: [..., factorial, 10, factorial % 10, oldsum]
   +       # Add top items together
           #   Stack: [..., factorial, 10, factorial % 10, oldsum, newsum]
    q      # Send that to the bottom
           #   Stack: [newsum, ..., factorial, 10, factorial % 10, oldsum]
     ;;    # Delete top two items
           #   Stack: [newsum, ..., factorial, 10]
       ,   # Integer divide top two items
           #   Stack: [newsum, ..., factorial, 10, factorial/10]
        s; # Delete the second item
           #   Stack: [newsum, ..., factorial, factorial/10]
```

And the loop starts again, until `factorial/10` equals 0.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 47 bytes

```
f(n,a){return n?f(n-1,a*n):a?a%10+f(0,a/10):0;}
```

usage:

```
f(n,a){return n?f(n-1,a*n):a?a%10+f(0,a/10):0;}
main() {
  printf("answer: %d\n",f(10,1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 3 bytes

```
ḟẹ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO@Q937dT@/9/SwvR/FAA)

Same "algorithm" as the [v1 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100832/8774) by @Fatalize, just with better encoding.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 57 bytes

```python
import math
lambda n:sum(map(int,str(math.factorial(n))))
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/E6TZ)

Comment: Could you use back ticks instead of str?

Comment: @nedla2004 That would append an `L` once the factorial is big enough to become a long.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge 93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

Saved 2 bytes do to using get instead of quotes. This let me shift the top 2 lines over 1, reducing unnecessary white space.

[Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=JiM6PF92IzotMQo6IFwqJDw6X14jCmc6OnY-OTErJSswMApfdiM8XnAwMDwvKzE5CkA-JCQu&input=MTA)

```
&#:<_v#:-1
: \*$<:_^#
g::v>91+%+00
_v#<^p00</+19
@>$$.
```

Explanation:

```
&#:<                Gets an integer input (n), and reverses flow direction
&#:< _v#:-1         Pushes n through 0 onto the stack (descending order)

:  \*$<:_^#         Throws the 0 away and multiplies all the remaining numbers together

(reorganized to better show program flow):
vp00< /+19 _v#<    Stores the factorial at cell (0, 0). Pushes 3 of whatever's in
> 91+%+ 00g ::^    cell (0, 0). Pops a, and stores a / 10 at (0, 0),
                   and adds a % 10 to the sum.

@>$$.              Simply discards 2 unneeded 0s and prints the sum.
```

Comment: You are correct. I'm working on a new version. FYI, I'm using quickster.com, because others that I found didn't treat `\` correctly when there was only one # in the stack.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this code only works properly in the [Befunge-98](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=JiM6PCBfdiM6LTEKOiAgXCokPDpfXiMKIiAiOnY-OTErJSsKX3YjOjxecDIxPC8rMTkKQD4kJC4&input=MTA) version, probably because of the put method.

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/31BN2comvkbZSpdLC0TF2CgocBlAhPS1LQ3TDQy0VYF0gQGXgoKDng1QhwEA) which also handles 0 correctly

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6 - <strike>61</strike> 54 Bytes

```
n=>eval(`for(j of''+(a=_=>!_||_*a(~-_))(n,t=0))t-=-j`)
```

**EDIT:** Thank you Hedi and ETHproductions for shaving off 7 bytes. I'll have to remember that t-=-j trick.

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a couple bytes in various ways: `n=>{a=_=>!_||_*a(~-_);t=0;for(j of''+a(n))t-=-j;return t}`

Comment: @ETHproductions Some more bytes can be saved with eval : `n=>eval(\`for(j of''+(a=_=>!_||_*a(~-_))(n,t=0))t-=-j\`)`

Comment: @Hedi I know, I was taking it one step at a time :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 112 bytes

```
@set/af=1,t=0
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/af*=%%i
:g
@set/at+=f%%10,f/=10
@if %f% gtr 0 goto g
@echo %t%
```

Conveniently `set/a` works on a variable's current value, so it works normally inside a loop. Only works up to 12 due to the limitations of Batch's integer type, so in theory I could save a byte by assuming `f<1e9`:

```
@set/af=1,t=0
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/af*=%%i
@for /l %%i in (1,1,9)do @set/at+=f%%10,f/=10
@echo %t%
```

But that way lies madness... I might as well hard-code the list in that case (97 bytes):

```
@call:l %1 1 1 2 6 6 3 9 9 9 27 27 36 27
@exit/b
:l
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @shift
@echo %2
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```
f=(n,m=1,t=0)=>n?f(n-1,n*m):m?f(n,m/10|0,t+m%10):t
```

Only works up to `n=22` due to floating-point accuracy limitations.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to cole!*

```
1#.10#.inv!
```

This simply applies sum (`1#.`) to the digits (using inverse `inv` of base conversion `#.` with a base of `10`) of the factorial (`!`) of the argument.

### Test cases

Note: the last two test cases are bigints, as marked by a trailing `x`.

```
   f=:10#.inv!
   (,. f"0) 10 19 469x 985x
 10    27
 19    45
469  4140
985 10053
```

Comment: You can use `"."0":` to get digits

Comment: 11 bytes: `1#.,.&.":@!` which requires extended precision for smaller cases too (unsure why). Also 11 bytes: `1#.10#.inv!`.

Answer (score 2):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 60 bytes

```
a=1
Loop,%1%
a*=A_Index
Loop,Parse,a
b+=A_LoopField
Send,%b%
```

AutoHotkey doesn't have a built-in factorial function and the loop functions have long names for their built-in variables. The first loop is the factorial and the second is adding the digits together.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>63</s> 60 bytes

-3 byte for `do...while` loop.

```c
i;f(n){i=n;while(--n)i*=n;do n+=i%10;while(i/=10);return n;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```c
i;
f(n){
 i=n;
 while(--n)
  i*=n;
 do
  n+=i%10;
 while(i/=10);
 return n;
}

main() {
 printf("%d\n",f(10));
}
```

Comment: Do we define f (n) as `int` by default?

Comment: @MukulKumar this is standard in C, if there is no type then `int` is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

**Q/KDB+ 41 Bytes**

```
sum{:"I"$string x}over'string prd 1+til n
```

Breakdown:

```
string prd 1+til n
```

Get the product from 1 to n

```
{:"I"$string x}
```

Function that accepts a string x and returns it converted to an integer.

```
over'
```

Iterate over the argument to it's right to the function on the left, passing each item in individually.

```
sum
```

Sum up the numbers output by the function at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
<?=array_sum(str_split(gmp_fact($argv[1])));
```

Well it's not clever, but it works. That said it turned out better than I thought (I thought I'd need to use `gmp_strval()` too).

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 3 bytes [(old version)](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/91012c7cefde6d8d5b09c33cf8a97883f6357431)

```
SBs
```

Explanation:

```
SB  -  product(range(1, input+1))
  s - digit_sum(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 61 bytes

```
{"${(1..it).inject{i,r->i*r}}".collect{0.parseInt(it)}.sum()​}​
```

Groovy doesn't even have factorial built-ins.

`"${(1..it).inject{i,r->i*r}}"` - Compute factorial as string.

`.collect{0.parseInt(it)}` - Turn the string into an array of integers.

`.sum()​` - Sum 'em.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>119</strike> 116 Bytes

*Edit: Saved 3 Bytes thanks to @TheLethalCoder*

Golfed:

```
long F(int n){long f=1;int s=0;for(;n>1;)f*=n--;foreach(var c in f.ToString().ToList())s+=int.Parse(c+"");return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public long F(int n)
{
  long f = 1;
  int s = 0;
  for (; n > 1;)
    f *= n--;
  foreach (var c in f.ToString().ToList())
    s += int.Parse(c + "");
  return s;
}
```

Tried both a `long` and an `Int64` and it won't take higher than `n=20`, ultimately went with `long` because it is shorter...

Testing:

```
  Console.WriteLine(new DigitalSumFactorial().F(10));
  //27
  Console.WriteLine(new DigitalSumFactorial().F(19));
  //45
  Console.WriteLine(new DigitalSumFactorial().F(20));
  //54
```

Comment: You can compile to a `Func<int, long>` to save bytes, the for loop can be simplified to `for (; i > 1;)` and then set `i = n` outside the loop above and post decrement `i` in the loop i.e. `f *= i--;`. I think the `ToList()` isn't needed although I haven't tried it and you will need to add `using System.Linq;` into the byte count for the `ForEach` part

Comment: `int.Parse(c+"")` can be replaced with `c-30` I think...

Comment: Its 48 not 30 I read the hex code by accident, also you can't remove the `ToList`, putting all of that together is 113 bytes including the 18 for the using statement: `using System.Linq;n=>{long f=1;int s=0,i=n;for(;i>1;)f*=i--;f.ToString().ToList().ForEach(c=>s+=c-48);return s;};`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks for the tips :) I've had another play around with it and saved 3 Bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 22 bytes

```
@sum <>""prod rng1+1#0
```

This only works for inputs <= 21.

Usage:

```
(@sum <>""prod rng1+1#0)10
```

## Explanation

Increment argument, tail-exclusive range from 1 to result, product, split over empty string, and sum.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 80 bytes (74bytes for 32bit integer)

```
let rec s=function|0L->0L|y->y%10L+s(y/10L)
let g x={1L..x}|>Seq.fold (*) 1L|>s
```

## F#, 98 bytes (96bytes for 32bit integer)

```
let f x=([1L..x]|>List.fold (*) 1L).ToString().ToCharArray()|>Array.fold (fun a c-> a+int(c)-48) 0
```

Test with

```
f 10L
g 10L
```

Thanks to ais523 for the anonymous match function and formatting help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Your answers are actually slightly better than you thought; unless it's vital to your program, you can remove the newline at the end of a file and save a byte that way. (You can produce the nicely formatted headings we use elsewhere by starting the heading with a `#` sign.) Also, I think F# has the `function` notation for creating an anonymous match block (e.g. you can use `let rec s=function|0L` rather than `let rec s x=match x with|0L`); that should help you get your code a bit shorter.

Comment: Thank you, it's the first time I saw the anonymous match. I select the functions in my code editor which told me 81 characters selected without the newline. I'm wondering if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 73 bytes

```
#N::((sum (map (split (+ "" (prod (seq 1 N))) "") #C::((- (asc C) 48)))))
```

I'm not sure if I should be counting `import` calls. Here is how you would use the above snippet:

```
(
    (import "lists")
    (def f #N::((sum (map (split (+ "" (prod (seq 1 N))) "") #C::((- (asc C) 48))))))
    (print (f 10))
)
```

It works by calculating the factorial using `prod/1`, converts it to a string by doing `(+ "" value)`, splits and maps the string to get the numeric value of each number (ASCII code - 48.) Lastly, we `sum/1` the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
!Ś
```

Explanation:

```
        Implicit input
!       Get factorial
 Ś      Sum the digits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f9f8eis//@NTAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
Êìx
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=yux4&input=OA==)

Get the factorial, split to a digit array and reduce by addition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 78 bytes

```
proc S n {proc F n {expr $n?($n)*\[F $n-1]:1}
expr [join [split [F $n] ""] +]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@hGsxyA7FSKwqKFFTy7DVU8jS1YqLdgGxdw1grw1ousEx0Vn5mnkJ0cUFOZokCWDZWQUkpVkE7tvZ/Tm5iAcgILkMDLkNLLhMzSy5LC1OuWqDxpSXFQKVWMQrRwSAttf8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 10 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/10\*/1+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/19b39AgRkvfUFvR0OD/fwA)

Explanation to follow.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 70 bytes

A lambda from `long` to `int`. Breaks for input over 20.

```java
n->{var f=n;while(n>1)f*=--n;return(f+"").chars().map(c->c-48).sum();}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XY7NasMwEITP9lMsOUlNJZrSQ0Gxj4VCe8qx9LBVJEeuvDb6cQnBz@4qNKfCwgzDzPL1OKPoj9/rlL@806A9xgjv6AgudXULY8JUxDpCD31ZyJyclzaTTm4k@XIz@7eRunt4pWQ6E1qw0Kwk2suMAWxD6ufkvGHU7ri9a4QgFUzKgZjdbjZc6hOGyLgccGJatFo8PXMZ88C4WtZK1f9x5tEdYSik7JCCo@7jEzB0kV/BKzsGYL7ggIMGdqrIvoHHh6vZluCvVR3OMZlBjjnJqfxIvsBInCZ/Zo5zVSpLXW5ZfwE)

## Java 10, 163 bytes

Fully arbitrary precision. A lambda from `BigInteger` to `BigInteger`.

```java
n->{var i=n;var f=n;while(n.compareTo(n.ONE)>0)f=f.multiply(n=n.subtract(n.ONE));return(f+"").chars().mapToObj(c->i.valueOf(c-48)).reduce(n.ZERO,(a,b)->a.add(b));}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bVDBasMwDD23XyF6slliWuhGuy45DDrYYQusPW3soCR26sxxgmOnlJJvz5yt7DAKxk@SpSe/V2KHYZl/DY1LlcwgU9i28IJSw3k6uRRbi9aDkBoVlH6COSsVE05nVtaaPV2Ch5@3Cu2BPcriWVtecBPAtWoMAqJBh/G5QwMy0psRhcfjQSpONMvqqkHD97WPk9ctjedURIJVTlnZqBPRkWatS63BzF5a6MZw64wm4mY2oyw7oGkJ9aubfZ2kJcnCWLIOleOJ8MlyRSkzPHfZuO99@5YEBIOUhjEyzHOSesJ@mGym/43oaplD5T0iO2ukLj4@AU3R0tGyiagNEFXrAiTcg@ZHGBPfcl7MA1isA1je@Wu9uu1/Bya7U2t5xWpnWePprPICGDajyGvW/SmQ1H/QE/RTf/rhGw)

### Ungolfed

```java
n -> {
    var i = n;
    var f = n;
    while (n.compareTo(n.ONE) > 0)
        f = f.multiply(n = n.subtract(n.ONE));
    return (f + "").chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> i.valueOf(c - 48))
        .reduce(n.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -MMath::BigInt -p`, 43 bytes

Supports arbitrarily large factorials.

```perl
$_=sum(Math::BigInt->new($_)->bfac()=~/./g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NFfDN7Ekw8rKKTPdM69E1y4vtVxDJV5T1y4pLTFZQ9O2Tl9PP13z/39LC9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fZH1ALk@mcUlVlahJZk5IBP/6xYAAA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum,product -p`, 27 bytes

Cannot handle extremely large factorials due to overflow.

```perl
$_=product 1..$_;$_=sum/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ragKD@lNLlEwVBPTyXeGihQXJqrr6ef/v@/ocG//IKSzPy84v@6vj6ZxSVWVqElmTkgBTpQXf91CwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```scala
1.to(_).product+""map(_-48)sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2loFCWmKOQZqXgmVeiYGsHof4b6pXka8Rr6hUU5aeUJpdoKynlJhZoxOuaWGgWl@b@twZqKyjKzCvJydNI0zA00NREFbAEC@jrI4RMzIBiCiH5@Qo5iUXpqWiylhamQB21/wE)

And a 34 byte solution without postfix syntax:

```scala
x=>(""+1.to(x).product:\0)(_+_-48)
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XlQu3L5dR7SIMSWEKMuhQg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
Sra
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTcmEiLCI5ODUiXQ==)

```
Sra
  a  # (num) range [1, a]
 r   # (lst) product
S    # (num) digit sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java8 -  112 Chars

(First time here...)

```
String.valueOf(LongStream.rangeClosed(2,i).reduce(1,(a,b)->a*b)).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 65 bytes

```
(fn[i](apply +(map #(-(int %)48)(str(apply *(range 1(inc i)))))))
```

Straightforward, character `\0` has integer value of 48.

Easier to follow steps:

```
(defn f [i] (->> i inc (range 1) (apply *) str (map #(- (int %) (int \0)) (apply +)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

Julia functions are generic across input types, and generate optimized code for each combination of input types. This function works with machine sized integers or arbitrary precision integers depending on the type of the argument. eg

```
f(10) = 27
f(50) = -97 # overflowed
f(big(50)) = 216 # no overflow, but slower due to use of BigInt
```

```julia
x->sum(digits(prod(1:x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXrrg0VyMlMz2zpFijoCg/RcPQqkJTU/N/al4Kl0NxRn65QpqGoYEmnG2KxE7KTAfxNf///w8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
n->sumdigits(n!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1664NDclMz2zpFgjT1Hzf2JBQU6lRp6Crp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkaeRpauooRBsa6CgYWuoomJgBCUsL01jN/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 66 bytes

```python
import math;print(sum(map(int,str(math.factorial(int(input()))))))
```

It gets factorial of number, splits it into an array, then prints it!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
:p[]&V!Us
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N@qIDpWLUwxtPi/S8h/Iy4zLkMDLkNLLiMjAA)

MATL port of Stewie Griffin's Octave answer. Works up to n=22, same as the Octave and R answers.

`:p` - factorial.
`[]&V` - string representation of the number, fully expanded (without the `[]&`, larger numbers use the scientific notation which won't do for our purposes).
`!U` transpose and convert back to numbers, getting individual digits.
`s` - sum those digits.

The `[]&` part can be removed for -3 bytes, but then the range is further limited to only work up to 17, instead of 22.

I could stretch the input range to 23 with a couple of tricks, but that costs an additional 20 bytes:

[`:1w5X2Y%"@*t10\~?10/]][]&V!Us`](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3A1w5X2Y%25%22%40%2at10%5C~%3F10%2F%5D%5D%5B%5D%26V%21Us&inputs=23&version=20.9.1)

(basically, use the `uint64` data type instead of the usual `double`, multiply by each number upto the given number, but divide away 10 whenever our product is divisible by it (since trailing zeros add nothing to the digit sum).)

That seems to be as far as we can go with MATLAB/MATL without doing an ad-hoc implementation of bignum in the program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
‼∑
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%BC%E2%88%91&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

A very literal interpretation of the challenge: `sum_of_digits_of(factorial(input))`

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 21 bytes

```ruby
:+|:/&:*|:digits|:sum
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWW620a6z01ay0aqxSMtMzS4prrIpLcyFyywsU3KINDWIhvAULIDQA)

### Explanation

```
:+ | :/ & :* | :digits | :sum

:+ |                           # Range 1..n, then
     :/ & :* |                 # Reduce with product, then
               :digits | :sum  # Sum digits
```

Answer (score 0):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 19 bytes

```
sum 10 vs prd 1+til
```

## k, 11 bytes

```
+/10\:*/1+!
```

`prd 1+til` generate the factorial of input

`10 vs` convert factorial to digits

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 24 bytes (non-competing)

```
sum(10fPart(.1seq(int(Ans!/₁₀^(I)),I,0,int(log(Ans!
```

Only works for nonnegative integers up to 18, inclusive, and works up to 20 if you round to the nearest multiple of 9 when the input is greater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 1 byte

```
w
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhYLy5cUJyUXQ3kLFltamEKYAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
wS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi8qDlxQnJRdDuQsWW1qYQpgA)