# Sum power of digits

Tags: code-golf, math

## Challenge :

Given two non-negative integers `(X and Y > 1)` calculate the sum of digits of their powers . i.e : sum of digits of `X ^ Y` .

---

## Input :

Two non-negative integers `X` and `Y`

---

## Output :

The sum of digits of X raised to power Y `X ^ Y`.

## Examples :

```
5 , 2                    ---> 7
9 , 4                    ---> 18
3 , 17                   ---> 27
```

Both numbers will be greater than 1

---

## Restrictions :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code (in bytes) for each language wins.

---

## Notes :

All input will be valid. i.e : Both inputs will be greater than 1 and will be integers.

Comment: You shouldn't immediately answer your own question. It is generally frowned upon.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100823/factorial-digit-sum?rq=1)

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk : ok , will take care not to do this again

Comment: I'm not really sure how a question that has 14 answers can get 8 downvotes with no negative comments to explain why. Perhaps I don't fully understand the rules. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: @ElP See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156100/quartic-summation#comment380406_156100

Comment: I'm tempted to answer `1` since in base `X>1`, `X`is `10`, so `X^Y` is 1 followed by `Y` zeros. that's always the sum of the digits, and the question didn't specify what base must be used.

Comment: @KellyLowder : You have to pass all the tests that are given **at the least** and if answering in `1` will pass the above mentioned tests (no converting) then be my guest. (Also nice idea. )

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
(x,y)->sumdigits(x^y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdLCoAgFEbhrfw08sJ10ItoUBsJAykUweLSA3L1VqPzHbFH0F6yw4CsHk6kx/Pe1uDDdapnTpStSExKoEfIEfbrY/FPgcXGqBxDiBjT1DIq86FnNH9rRtkZQ/kF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Jelly trivialises this task</sup>

```
*DS
```

A dyadic link accepting a positive integer, X, on the left and a positive integer, Y, on the right which returns the resulting positive integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/LJfj////G/w3NAQ)**

#### How?

```
*DS - Link: X, Y
*   - exponentiate X to the Y
 D  - to a list of its digits
  S - sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>60</s> 56 Bytes

This is my first time golfing, and I think this code can be shortened. Feel free to help and improve this.
Edit: Does not work when you give it a and b such that a^b is over 2^31.

4 Bytes saved thanks to Dennis.

```
i,q;f(a,b){for(i=0,q=pow(a,b);q;q/=10)i+=q%10;return i;}
```

[test it by editing the numbers in the printf](https://ideone.com/mTxbHR)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If you declare `i` and `q` as globals, you can save a few bytes by using a `for loop. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclLCsIwEADQtT1FKBQSnGLiB5EhN3ETU1MG2qSJVRelVzdW192@Z@vW2pwJIjpu4CYmFxInLSHqIbz/hBHjTispaKtjpSSm@/hMnhHOmfzIekOevwI1opiKzZAWc7ysmqsvgTl@Asb2QuBKXZY6rtcBmDr/as4f6zrTPnLd9V8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:sum(map(int,str(a**b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8mquDRXIzexQCMzr0SnuKRII1FLK0lTU/N/QRFQRCNNw1THSFOTC8az1DFB4hnrGJoDlQIA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 8 bytes

Prompts for y followed by x:

```
+/⍎¨⍕⎕*⎕
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>12 bytes</strike> 11 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Cows quack

```
1#.,.&.":@^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1dPTU9JSsHOL@a3IpcKUmZ@QrmCqkKRhBmJZApgmEaQxkGppX/AcA)

`^` power

`,.&.":` convert to list of digits

`1#.` add up the digits

Comment: Try `1#.,.&.":@^`

Comment: @Cows quack - Thanks, I should have tried it :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```hs
x%y=sum[read[d]|d<-show$x^y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC8IgGAbge7/iPTgoyCA6BMPtslPnjmIgKNto6tAvptB/t3V/nkmnt12WWnNTuvRxMlptpFFfI3iawsbyq6jq9OzRwYQDIPMZRUFwOL3i@PdoWzwpzn4E7/HwdMIFW4gmQbAeo6UheLKe0v7X3REYMhqUesP1/gM)

<sub>-1 byte thanks to user9549915</sub>

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctBC8IgGAbge7/iPTgoyCA6BMPtslPnjmIgKNto6tAvptB/t3V/nkmnt12WWnNTuvRxMlptpFFfI3iawsbyq6jq9OzRwYQDIPMZRUFwOL3i@PdoWzwpzn4E7/HwdMIFW4gmQbAeo6UheLKe0v7X3REYMhqUesP1/gM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

Power ; implicitly coerce to list; sum

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcqX0f5k5Y8/@/EZcpAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 31 bytes

```
a=>b=>{n=0fors in''..a^b n-=-s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P9HWLsnWrjrP1iAtv6hYITNPXV1PLzEuSSFP11a3uPZ/QVFmXolGmoalpoaJpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
ＩΣＩＸＮＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0F8IIyC9PLdLwzCsoLfErzU0CsjV1FFC4YGD9/78ll8l/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ   First input as a number
     Ｎ  Second input as a number
   Ｘ    Power
  Ｉ     Cast to string
 Σ      Sum of digits
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: One of the few times such a hacky sum builtin is useful :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shagy

```
pV ìx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyBM4fCaiv//LXVMAA)

Comment: Welcome to Japt! You can save a byte by removing the space before `x`; `N.ì(f)` converts `N` to an array of digits, passes that array through `f` and then converts back to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.

```javascript
X=>Y=>eval([...''+X**Y].join`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/C1i7S1i61LDFHI1pPT09dXTtCSysyVi8rPzMvQTtB839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmmhpGmJheqoKWmhgmGoLGmhqG5puZ/AA)

## Explanation :

```javascript
X =>                      // First input X
    Y =>                  // second input Y
        eval(             // evaluate
            [...''+       // convert what is next to string and map to array
            X**Y].        // X raised to power Y 
                join`+`   // join them into a string with a plus sign between each
        )                 // The whole thing gets evaluated using `eval`
```

---

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/C1i7S1i61LDFHI1pPT09dXTtCSysyVi8rPzMvQTtB839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmmhpGmJheqoKWmhgmGoLGmhqG5puZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
ssM`^F
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssM%60%5EF&input=2%0A5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B5%2C2%5D%0A%5B9%2C4%5D%0A%5B3%2C17%5D&debug=0)

If the list input isn't allowed, you can just replace the `F` with `E` and it'll take in two integers (one on each line) but do the operation in reverse order from input order.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{(x**y).digits.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7Jao0JLq1JTLyUzPbOkWK@4NLf2f4FCWrSpjlEsF4hhqWMCYRjrGJrH/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
X=>g=(Y,d=X**Y)=>d&&d%10+g(Y,d/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/C1i7dViNSJ8U2QksrUtPWLkVNLUXV0EA7HSSob2hQY6D5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DVFPDSFOTC1XQUlPDBEPQWFPD0FxT8z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
(* ***).comb.sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfQ0tBS0tLUy85PzdJr7g09781F1dxYqVCmoapgo6CkaY1lGcJ5JnAecZAnqG5pvV/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 11 bytes

```
XWaSD}|lR+B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvhv6Ohu7Obp6e5XY/0/Ijwx2KW2JidI2@n/f1MFIy5LBRMuYwVDcwA)

A function that accepts X and Y on the stack and leaves the result as the only value on the stack.

#### Example full program & How it works

```
1AGIE;IGN
XWaSD}|lR+B

1AG          Register row 1 as function G
   IE;       Take input X as int; halt if EOF
      I      Take input Y as int
       GN    Call G with stack [X Y] and print the result as int
             Repeat indefinitely

X            n = X**Y
 W    |      While top is nonzero...
  aSD          Pop n, push n / 10 and n % 10
     }         Move the remainder to the bottom
             Now the stack contains the digits
       lR+   Sum everything
          B  Return
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
║▼δ&
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ba1feb26&i=5+2&a=1)

Unpacked:

```
|*E|+
```

[Run and debug this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C*E%7C%2B&i=5+2&a=1)

Explanation:

```
|*E|+ Full program, implicit input
      Stack: 5 2
|*    Power
      Stack: 25
  E   Decimal digits
      Stack: [ 2, 5 ]
   |+ Sum array
      Stack: 7
      Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 44 Bytes

No loop, passing both arguments to the script.
[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZhttrGNoHmvNZW8HFLZNLCpKrIwvLs3VKC4pii8uyMks0QCrizaI1dKCsAxjNTWt//8HAA)

**Code**

```
<?=array_sum(str_split($argv[0]**$argv[1]));
```

This just takes both arguments calculates `X to the power of Y`, explodes the string into an array and adds each digit

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
Σd^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zilLj///8bmv83BgA) Takes `Y` followed by `X`.